# Set cell value Qtableview with QSqlRelationalTableModel

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a QTableView based on a QSqlRelationalTableModel. Editing, adding and deleting is no problem but I would like to change a field programaticaly.

(more specific: click on a field, pop-up a QFileDialog to select a file and then filling that field with the result).

How do I do that?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

1. QSqlRelationalTableModel.record to get the record
2. QSqlRelationalTableModel.record.setvalue to change a value
3. QSqlRelationalTableModel.setrecord to write the record to the database